# Listing of shared links through Box API

Tags: box-api

How can I get a list of shared links accessible to the company through the Box API v2? It appears that only links that have been "saved" appear in the item list of folders. However it also appears I can set a default share for all files across the entire enterprise.

Answer (score 2):

There is no method to get shared links across an entire account.  They must be retrieved from folder or file objects directly via the `shared_link` attribute. A shared link is only created with an explicit action, such as http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-create-a-shared-link-for-a-file; they can never be created by default by an enterprise administrator.  However, an enterprise administrator does have the ability to set default shared link settings once they're created, such as "Default new links to Your Company".  Here is a more detailed overview from our support page: https://support.box.com/entries/20894888-Shared-Links-Overview-and-FAQs